# Bash script to run python script for all images in all subdirectories

Tags: command-line, bash

I have subfolders in current directory like this:

```
ls

apples  bananas  oranges  potatoes
```

Each subfolder includes different number of .jpg images.

```
cd apples

ls

000000522638.jpg  000000522713.jpg  000000522751.jpg
```

I have custom python program downloaded from different source which modifies images, and takes input image path and output image path as argument:

```
python modifyImage.py path/to/input/image.jpg path/to/output/image.jpg
```

**Problem statement:**

I want to apply this program for each image in given subdirectories(apples,oranges etc.). There are a lot of folders and images with arbitrary names, so I can not do this by hand. Possible solution would be, firstly finding all *.jpg image paths and send these as argument to python script.

And I made script for updating *.jpg files only in current directory like this

```
for file in *.jpg
do
  python modifyImage.py /"$file" /"$file"
done
```

But I need above script to **work with subdirectories**. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Super User](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86722/how-do-i-loop-through-only-directories-in-bash?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) they tell us how to loop through sub-directories:

```bash
for d in */ ; do
    echo "$d"
done
```

Using this reference you can use nested `for` loops:

```bash
for d in */ ; do
    for file in "$d"/*.jpg
    do
        python modifyImage.py /"$file" /"$file"
    done
done
```

Comment: It works, thanks for precise answer and explanation. :)